# Can't print tag 'content' anymore

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I had a perfectly well working scraper for TripAdvisor, it met all my needs, then I tried to use it after a four day break and something went wrong, I quickly realized that TA had changed some of the tags, I made the appropriate changes and I still couldn't get it working as before. I want to grab the value of the 'content' tag within an element.
This is the element:

```
<div class="prw_rup prw_common_bubble_rating bubble_rating" data-prwidget-init="" data-prwidget-name="common_bubble_rating"><span alt="5 of 5 bubbles" class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50" content="5" property="ratingValue" style="font-size:18px;"></span></div>
```

and here is the code:

```
for bubs in data.findAll('div',{'class':"prw_rup prw_common_bubble_rating bubble_rating"}):
                print([img["content"] for img in bubs.select("img[content]")])
```

but now it only gives me an empty '[]' instead of the content which is '5'.
Anybody know what may have changed?

here is the rest of my code

```html
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
theurl = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147364-c3-Cayman_Islands-Hotels.html"
thepage = urllib
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
base_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com"
urls = []
init_info = []
init_data = open('/Users/paribaker/Desktop/scrapping/TripAdvisor/Inv/speccaydata.txt', 'w')
for link in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('/Hotel_Review')):
    urls.append(base_url + (link.get('href')).strip("#REVIEWS"))
def remove_duplicates(urls):
    output= []
    seen = set()
    for line in urls:
        if line not in seen:
            output.append(line)
            seen.add(line)
    return output
urls2 = remove_duplicates(urls)
for url in urls2:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("taplc_prodp13n_hr_sur_review_filter_controls_0_filterLang_ALL").click()
        print("succesfull")
        moreinfo = driver.page_source
        moresoup = BeautifulSoup(moreinfo,"html.parser")
        driver.close()
    #moreinfo = urllib
    #moreinfo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    #moresoup = BeautifulSoup(moreinfo,"html.parser")
    except:
        print("none")
    for data in moresoup.findAll('div', {"class":"heading_2014 hr_heading"}):
        try:
            for title in data.findAll('h1',{'id':"HEADING"}):
                init_info.append(title.text.strip("\n")+ ",\t")
            for add_data in data.findAll('span',{'class':'format_address'}):
                print((add_data.find('span',{'class':'street-address'}).text +",\t"))
                init_info.append(add_data.find('span',{'class':'street-address'}).text +",\t")
                init_info.append(add_data.find('span',{'class':'locality'}).text + ",\t")
                init_info.append(add_data.find('span',{'class':'country-name'}).text + ",\t")
            for reviews in data.findAll('a',{'class':'more taLnk'}):
                init_info.append(reviews.text).strip("\n")
                init_info.append(", \t")
            #init_info.append([img["alt"] for img in stars.select("img[alt]")])
            #init_info.append([img["content"] for img in stars.select("img[content]")])
        except :
            init_info.append("N/A" + ", /t")
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the HTML? (What exactly is `data`?)

Comment: Im using BS4 but I also have a Selenium parser for a specific function.

Comment: import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Comment: theurl = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147364-c3-Cayman_Islands-Hotels.html

Comment: for data in moresoup.findAll('div', {"class":"heading_2014 hr_heading"}):

Comment: It would be best to add that information into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the `content="5"` attribute is a `span`, not an `img`.

Does this get what you want?

```
for bubs in data.findAll('div',{'class':"prw_rup prw_common_bubble_rating bubble_rating"}):
            print([elem["content"] for elem in bubs.select("span[content]")])
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, thats it, I had tried it I thought but I guess not. Thank You so much